# XMPP server in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, xmpp, ejabberd, openfire

Which XMPP server would you recommend for use in Amazon Web Services, running on EC2 instances?

It should scale, with automatic (or at least easy) clustering being very useful - it's scaling should also support an XMPP server component. It would be nice if the automatic scaling could work with Amazon Auto Scaling.

Which XMPP server (or even a different cloud offering) would you use? As far as I can tell OpenFire and Ejabberd are the most popular choices, but I'm concerned they won't scale well on EC2 instances.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge there is no XMPP server with automatic clustering.You should be aware that automatic clustering with XMPP is extremely difficult because it is a connected protocol and it cannot be totally transparent, unless you only want to support HTTP (XMPP over BOSH).

You will end up with question like: what do you do with running TCP/IP connection when you want to remove a node ? Do you want to migration session when adding a node ? What do you do with running TCP/IP connection.

ejabberd has good clustering support however and it runs extremely well on EC2 and is very stable. This is your best bet.

OpenFire to my knowledge is not an option with no real, largely available clustering support.

Comment: I am facing problem in connection ejabberd server on amazon ec2 Please help me in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227480/not-able-to-connect-ejabberd-server-on-amazon-using-xmpp-framework-of-ios