# Not able to connect ejabberd server on Amazon using XMPP framework of iOS

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am working on XMPP framework to create Text chat application. We have configure ejabberd server on amazaon ec2. I have tested my application on locally configured server and was working fine but as i replaced host and username with amazone ec2 details i am getting error "Read Operation timed out". I searched for help but issue is still unresolved.

Please help me in find out the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out solution for my own problem. I downloaded the latest framework from

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/archive/master.zip.

Also i checked firewall settings with my network team. Now i am able to connect to amazon ec2 server.

Thanks.

Comment: i configured ejabberd on amazon , could you help me out to connect through ios